# Android Studio how to loop through songs MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

everyone, I'm currently having a problem in my code once the first song stops playing it automatically goes to the third because of the even OnClickListener, but once the second song stops playing the third song doesn't play automatically. How can I fix my code so that it will call the OnClickListener again once the second stop, and maybe more(I might add more songs) the code is below thanks.

Comment: please ignore the comment about the loop in the play method that is a typo thanks in advance

Comment: Then [edit your post](//stackoverflow.com/posts/48799249/edit) and remove it.

Comment: mButton.performClick(); fire the onClick listener.

Answer (score 2):

You should not create so many instances of `MediaPlayer` like that, a instance of `MediaPlayer` can play multiple songs. Just set another media source using this:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(yourSource);
```

You can loop the song by:

```
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

Comment: r u saying to remove  songs[nextSong].setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
    @Override public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
and put the two line of the code above instead?